# GCM Android is registration id should be saved?

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to build PhoneGap android application which gets GCM messages.
I used sample code for it, which initially receives registration ID from the server.
Is this ID should be received each time the application starts or I should save it first time and use later the saved ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to send Registration id to your own server and save it on your Server. So, that you can use it when sending push messages to GCM Server. GCM Server will send put messages to your device on the basis of that Registration id.

**UPDATE:**

For better clarification you could always watch the [Google I/O Videos](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/gooio2012/100/)

Answer (score 0):

You can get registration id by GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(context) anywhere.
You should not save it in your application.

Comment: But as I see each time I start the application I get different key.

Comment: You cant get different registration id.http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html.  Registration id will changes only when your application send register/unregister intent to a gcm server.